# Which is the redundant relationship in this ER Diagram and why?

Tags: database-design, erd

Which is the redundant relationship in this ER Diagram and why? A few of my friends and I have been trying to figure it out but keep going in circles.

[image]

where the attributes of each entity are as follows:

```
Employee: Employee_No, Name, Address and Telephone_No.
Department: Department_No, Name and Location.
Training Course: Course Code, Title, Start_Date and Description.
```

Comment: None of them are redundant, assuming they represent your requirements correctly. Can you tell us the requirements you are trying to model with this ER diagram?

Comment: The answer changes based on your assumptions which is why you have to explain your reasoning.

Comment: As Branko said, we need the requirements (the conceptual model) to be able to determine if this logical model is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

None of them are redundant. It's ok to have a loop.

You seem to be missing a many-many relationship (Employee Course) table, though.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that employees only attend training courses for their department, you could derive the department an employee works in according to the training courses they've taken.

Comment: And if an employee has not attended any training courses, we assume he hasn't been assigned to a department? Too many assumptions I think, that don't make much sense.

Answer (score -2):

That looks like a fan trap,therefore any assumptions in resolving that should be based solely on user/client requirements.